# Instagram Access Token Windows Store App C#

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-store, instagram-api

I want to get access token from instagram api in windows store app

Here's my code:

```
string endURL = "ms-app://..";  string clientID = "..";
Uri endUri = new Uri(endURL);
string startURL = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?"
                + "client_id=" + clientID
                + "&redirect_uri=" + endURL
                + "&response_type=code";
try
{
    WebAuthenticationResult result = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync
        (WebAuthenticationOptions.None, startUri);
    if (result.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success) {
        string token = webAuthenticationResult.ResponseData;
}
catch(Exception) { }
```

I get that error:

> The specified protocol is unknown. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800C000D)

Comment: Hi, did you ever solve this? I'm having a very similar issue with a custom OAuth server

Comment: Hi @nmilcoff, unfortunately I do not remember what I ended up with as this was 5 years ago. Hope you find a solution and post it here for others.

Comment: This blog post helped me solve the problem: https://jamesmclachlan.blogspot.com/2017/02/webauthenticationbroker-and-oauth2.html. In summary, the final URL was too long for the WebAuthenticationBroker. There is a max of 2083 characters

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you directly use InstaAPI
[**github**](https://github.com/yuvrajb/InstaAPI) & [**codeplex**](https://instaapi.codeplex.com/)?

---

```
List<Scope> scopes = new List<Scope>() { Scope.basic };
InstaConfig config = new InstaConfig("CLIENT_ID", "CLIENT_SECRET", "REDIRECT_URI", scopes);

// use this to redirect user for authenticating your application
String AuthenticationUriString = config.GetAuthenticationUriString(); 

OAuth oauth = new OAuth(config, "CODE_ATTACHED_WITH_REDIRECTEDURI_AFTERSUCCESSFUL_AUTHENTICATION");
AuthUser user = oauth.GetAuhtorisedUser();

Console.WriteLine(user.AccessToken);
```

Comment: what's "CODE_ATTACHED_WITH_REDIRECTEDURI_AFTERSUCCESSFUL_AUTHENTICATION" ?

Comment: @Ghanem If you look at the "Server-Side flow of Authentication" of [Instagram](https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/), after you redirect the user to authentication url, which can be obtained via `config.GetAuthenticationUriString();`, if the user authorizes your application then he/she will be redirected to the link that you defined as "REDIRECT_URI" along with the **code** parameter. 


Somewhat like this:
http://your-redirect-uri?code=CODE

The CODE in the above link is the second parameter to the **OAuth Constructor**